# Filtering data with timestamps

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, sampling

How to apply filter to data that was sampled in certain moments of time? Examples from documentation deal only with uniformly sampled data:

```
data = Table[SquareWave[i/100] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], {i, 225}];
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot /@ {data, LowpassFilter[data, .5]}]
```

I.e. time is not included in the array. How to apply similar filter to the case when sampling times are explicitly stated? The following fails:

```
data = Table[{i/100, SquareWave[i/100] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i,225}];
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot /@ {data, LowpassFilter[data, .5]}]
```

Comment: @kglr this won't work for non uniform sampling time: `data = Table[{(i/100)^2, 
    SquareWave[(i/100)^2] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i, 525}];`

Comment: @kglr this works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `TemporalData` or `TimeSeries` to your data:

```
data = TemporalData[Table[{i/100, SquareWave[i/100] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i,225}]];
ListLinePlot[{data, LowpassFilter[data, 60]}]
```

[image]

You can use `Timeseries` objects essentially like a `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
data0 = Table[{i/100 + RandomReal[{-0.005, 0.005}], 
    SquareWave[i/100] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i, 225}];
f = TimeSeries[data0, 
   "ResamplingMethod" -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}];
g = TimeSeries[data0, 
   "ResamplingMethod" -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}];
h = TimeSeries[data0, 
   "ResamplingMethod" -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 3}];
Plot[{f[t], g[t], h[t]}, {t, f["Times"][[1]], f["Times"][[-1]]}]
```

[image]

The default resampling method is of order 1 (piecewise-linear interpolation). You can get the `InterpolatingFunction` with `g["PathFunction"]`.

Also interesting for you might be to inspect other properties with `g["Properties"]` (this works also for `TemporalData` objects.

Comment: Is there any difference between `TimeSeries` and `TemporalData`?

Comment: How do I plot TimeSeries like a usual function?

Comment: This proved to work much faster than Timeseries.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = Table[{(i/100)^2, SquareWave[(i/100)^2] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i, 180}]; 
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot /@ {data, LowpassFilter[TimeSeries@data, Quantity[5, "Hertz"]]}]
```

[image]